# How can I give to user, execute another users's functions?

Tags: oracle, privileges, sql-grant

I want to give privileges to a user to call a function another users function.

I write this : `GRANT EXECUTE ANY FUNCTION TO user;`

but it doesn't work.

user need to call this:

```
call XXX.YYY.AlterAllInvalidObjects(NULL,'PACKAGE BODY');
```

but how can I give grant ?

NOTE : I don't want to use : `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION AlterAllInvalidObjects TO user;`
I need general solution not specific function name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO user;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2077938

will manage both functions and procedures.
You can't grant that way to functions only...

**EDIT**

the other way (but you'll have to run it every time the other user will create a new function to get all the grants):

Run

```
select 'GRANT EXECUTE ON '||owner||'.'||object_name||' TO user;'
from all_objects
where owner = 'xxx'
and object_type='FUNCTION';
```

and copy-paste-execute the result...

or use a SP doing the same thing (cursor on the query and execute immediate in loop)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it looks like you're asking about synonyms, not grants because grants doesn't help you to invoke call AlterAllInvalidObjects without mentioning the schema. Please consider about http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm